# Have you ever faced responsive issues on mobile while your site is responsible on browser?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I was facing this issue. When I change browser size, it works well but when viewed on real device, it was not responsive and instead showed the shrink-ed version of webpage.

Comment: Actually, no. I have my own boilerplate use it for all. Modernizr, respond.js, all the stuff goes in there

Comment: @Christina - We have those for responsiveness in different browser. I am talking about different devices(mobile or smart phone ).

Comment: If you have a boilerplate including the viewport meta tag, you just use that and not think about it

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the "viewport meta tag", which is very important. Adding this below mentioned one meta tag will resolve the issue.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

For more details view the below tutorial:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972